# How to change product category slug in bulk in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, permalinks, slug

I am working on a Woocoomerce site with many categories.
I have to add some text at the end of the categories (suffix) slug. Like "klm".
How to change product category slug in bulk in Woocommerce?

*For example,

Furniture > Kitchen Furniture

The permalink for the category is as follows:

"kitchen-furniture"*

What I want to do is add a new text (suffix) to the end of all (main category or subcategories).

*For example,

"kitchen-furniture-klm"*

Yes, this can be done from **wp-admin>Products>Categories**. However, as I said at the beginning, there are many categories.

There are [22 pages of entries for categories on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce%20category%20slug&s=4226819f-e78d-4fa2-aff6-da89b0c8faab). I've looked at almost all of them. However, I couldn't find what I was looking for. I would appreciate if someone could guide me where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: Please take database backup before execute following update query**

You can do this in database, using following query

```
UPDATE wp_terms SET slug = CONCAT(slug, '-klm') WHERE term_id IN(SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'product_cat')
```